# Getting key from array without looping when there is only one record

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array['2']['21'] = null;
```

I want to get `21` from array above without looping, is it possible? I want to do it for those arrays which have **ONLY 1** record in them. Obviously I'll have to use loop for others.

```
foreach ($array['2'] as $key => $value)
{
   echo $key;
   //I know this does the job wondering if there is simple function
}
```

I looked at [extract()](http://php.net/extract) but doesn't do my job.

Comment: If you cabn assign it directly, you can get its value directly. `echo $array['2']['21']`

Comment: if it contains only one record how could index 21 come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
$arr_keys  = array_keys($array['2']);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr_keys);
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: To get exactly what he wants, use `array_keys($array['2'])[0]`

Comment: Solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @BartFriederichs : No...it is caled as Array dereferencing which will be supported only in PHP 5.5 +

Comment: @MadMax : If it solves your problem dont forget to accept it, That may help some one to find the answer.